# PDF not showing via SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I was try to bind Azure SAS token into iframe for pdf file. It working into internet explorer but others. Others browser couldn't embed pdf file but downloaded.

But it working with google drive viewer. But my client not favor it.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you share the actual SAS URL?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because the `content-type` property of the blob is set as `application/octet-stream` (default for Azure Storage blobs). You can check it by observing the response headers in Chrome developer tools.

While IE and some other browsers are smart enough to detect the content type from content, Google Chrome does not and because it does not understand the content type, it simply downloads it.

To solve this issue, please set the content type property of the blob to `application/pdf` and then you should be able to see the PDF in the browser.